# Highlight Before and after the characters --

Tags: livecode, livecoding

I want to highlight the strings before and after '--'. Example good -- bad here i want to highlight good and bad. when ever the -- is comes then before and after the strings are become highlight. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following text in a field "mytext":

```
This text comes before -- this text comes after.
```

LiveCode (as most applications) does not allow discontinuous selections, so the 'select' command only works on continuous runs of text.

```
select word 1 to 3 of fld "mytext"
```

But you can simulate selection highlighting by setting the backgroundColor property of separate text runs:

```
put wordOffset("--",fld "mytext") into tWordIndex
set the backgroundColor of word 1 to tWordIndex - 1 of fld "mytext" to the hiliteColor
set the backgroundColor of word tWordIndex + 1 to -1 of fld "mytext" to the hiliteColor
```

Of course you can use any valid text chunk expression in the two 'set' statements, depending on what part of the text preceding and following the " -- " you want to "highlight".

To clear the backgroundColor from the field do this:

```
set the backgroundColor of char 1 to -1 of fld "mytext" to empty
```